# cargo ndk fails due to pkg-config issue

Tags: android, flutter, rust, android-ndk, rust-cargo

I think I've read every suggestion on the internet at this point to no avail, so I'm hoping I can get some help here.

### Repro

```
git clone https://github.com/banool/aclip.git
cd aclip/frontend/native
cargo ndk -t armeabi-v7a -o ../android/app/src/main/jniLibs build
```

The code in question: https://github.com/banool/aclip.

Relevant env:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/pkgconfig/
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Users/dport/Library/Android/sdk/ndk
```

### Output

Running the above gives me this: https://gist.github.com/d2564965bbd5e4d8bf72c3132c87255f.

Some thoughts on what's going on here:

- I see it says `NDK API level: 21`. Is this level not the same as the NDK level, which as you can see in the previous line is 24?
- I have tried setting `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` to the NDK directory. That gives me instead this rather cryptic error: https://gist.github.com/b28eae5f666fccaffe80278a5a8a80e1. I wonder if there is a better directory to use.
- I did everything here relevant to the second part, where I'm trying to use a newer NDK: http://cjycode.com/flutter_rust_bridge/template/setup_android.html.

I have set the libunwind stuff suggested here: http://cjycode.com/flutter_rust_bridge/template/setup_android.html. That helped with the gcc error in the second gist here, but I've still got the ssl and crypto errors.

Any tips on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I was able to skirt around the issue by doing this.

First, figure out what openssl crate version we're relying on:

```
$ cargo tree --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl -i openssl-sys | grep openssel
openssl-sys v0.9.74
└── openssl v0.10.40
```

Then add something like this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
openssl = { version = "0.10.40", features = ["vendored"] }
```

This avoids the need for the system openssl.